# EAAccessory showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter method always shows me empty and unable to list device

Tags: ios, external-accessory

I am trying to use the method `showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:nil completion:nil` to show a picker in my app but it always shows an empty list. I already included the protocol string in my app. If I use the device's setting page, I am able to see my MFI device and pair and connect to it. But it refuses to show it in the alert box that the picker generates. Any help? I am using iOS 7.0.

```
[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:nil completion:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error :%@", error);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"You make it! Well done!!!");
    }
}];
```

Comment: Does `[[EAAcessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories]` return anything?

Comment: Yup. It can return a list of my connected accessories. But now I am trying to get pairing done via this picker.